# Nautilus stop working after recent software updates

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

My latop has Ubuntu 18.04.1

The Nautilus (Files browser) stop working after recent software updates ( I believe it contains some updates to Nautilus).

I tried remove and install the Nautilus, just won't fix the issue.

I tried to launch it from Terminal window by typing 'nautilus' , the error message is:

nautilus: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3: undefined symbol: _ZN16WAVE_MetaHandler9kRIFFiXMLE

Answer (score 1):

Similar bug had caused in [multiple cases](https://bugs.launchpad.net/timeshift/+bug/1516255), where [the ones](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mir/+bug/1527137) that managed to fix it was by reinstalling the streamed broken package which in your case is `libexempi3`. Try reinstalling with,

```
sudo apt purge libexempi3
sudo apt install eog libexempi3 nautilus nautilus-share
sudo apt install -f
```

If that doesn't work, look for any libexemp library that is a dependency of nautilus in your system `apt depends nautilus | grep libexempi` and try reinstalling that package.

Comment: Bingo!  It perfectly solved the problem.   I purged libexempi3 first, then remove the Nautilus and reinstall it,  it pickup the correct libexempi3 dependency packages automatically.